# Как правильно зашифровать название

Tags: php, javascript, защита, md5

Данный вопрос относиться к проектированию, и кода реализации нет.

Делаю проект по созданию тестов. Такая проблема. Необходимо вывести информацию о всех тестах, которые есть для редактирования или удаления. Но появилась такая проблема. необходимо, например в в тег `a` поместить информацию о тесте, примерно так: `<a data-title="Название теста" data-id="1">Узнайте смысл жизни</a>`. 
Но если я правильно понимаю, то можно редактировать код страницы так, что отправятся другие значения, возможно я и ошибаюсь. 
Собственно проблема: как решить такую проблему и возможно реализовать какую-либо защиту.

Была следующая идея: в md5 зашифровать название теста, и поместить в отдельный столбец в таблице. При выборе проверять хеш название выбраного и из базы, которому соответствует `data-id`.

Прошу простить если не понятен вопрос.

Comment: Объясните, почему «можно редактировать код страницы так, что отправятся другие значения» вообще является проблемой?

Comment: Делайте проверку на бекенде. Нельзя доверять клиенту)

Comment: Это скорее вопрос валидации. Мне нужно быть увереным, что на сервер пришел выбранный пользователем, который соответствует тесту в бд. А тогда проблема будет, в том как реализовать, чтобы меня не обманули хакеры....

Comment: Если ответ на тест - один или несколько вариантов из предложенных, отправлять от клиента номера вариантов. Не давать юзеру отправлять значения напрямую.

И валидировать на стороне сервера, ессно. И дергать БД хранимыми процедурами.